# How to test lambda methods in Java using JUnit?

Tags: java, lambda, junit

I am using Java 8 and I have a method as below

```
CsvValidation csvValidate = (Reader fileCSV, Reader fileCSVSchema) -> {

    final Boolean failFast = false;
    final List<Substitution> pathSubstitutions = new ArrayList<Substitution>();
    final List<FailMessage> messages = CsvValidator.validate(fileCSV, fileCSVSchema, failFast, pathSubstitutions,
            false, false);

    if (messages.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Completed validation OK");
        return true;
    } else {

        for (final FailMessage message : messages) {
            if (message instanceof WarningMessage) {

                System.out.println("[WARN] " + message.getMessage());
            } else {

                System.out.println("[ERROR] " + message.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

I want to test this method using JUnit. Is there any way how can I test this method? It would be good if someone can provide me some useful links or even better if someone can provide me a sample how to test such methods.

Comment: Depending on the scope of that variable you would test them the same way you test a 'normal' method. Call it with some arguments and assert.

Comment: It's a good example for which to not use lambdas in the first place. Just declare it as a method. You can of course assign it to a `BiPredicate<Reader, Reader>` variable and test on that.

Comment: Yeah, took me some time to spot the lambda here, I would never have assumed in the first place that the whole method body was one. It's long, it has side-effects, it needs multiple variables to work, all those are red-flags for me when deciding whether a function would look better as a lambda.

Comment: @daniu, `CsvValidation` interface might extend `BiPredicate` in his code.

Comment: daniu is correct. You don't want to test this. You want to refactor it. It seems that you believe that everything is nail, now that you learned about the **lambda** hammer. Wrong: you don't use some syntactic element because you *can* - but because it makes sense. And surprise - it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: And beyond that: this code is simply written up in a "hard to test" manner. There is no point in trying to reasonable unit test something like this. That is why everybody keeps telling you to do TDD and to write your tests before you put down your superhard-to-test production code! Because then you are forced to put up something that can be tested, instead of writing code that is, as said: much harder to test than it could be.

Comment: @GhostCat my pleasure, the idea of an "hard to test" manor was fun enough that you I'm nearly sad you rewrote your comment ;)